# Ternary expression translation with i18next react js

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I am new to react js.
I want to create keys for the texts in the ternary expression.

```
import {useTransaltion} from "react-i18next"
function dummy(){
const {t} = useTranslation();
<Typography color="white" variant="h4">
    {restartLoading ? <LinearProgress /> : "Restart"}
</Typography>
```

how can I translate "Restart" .. because the following code gives me an error:

```
<Typography color="white" variant="h4">
    {restartLoading ? <LinearProgress /> : {t("Restart")}}
</Typography>
```

{t("Restart")} : there is an error here: Identifier expected.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to use curly braces again when you define one in the ternary inside of that you can use javascript as a normal single liner.

```
<Typography color="white" variant="h4">
    {restartLoading ? <LinearProgress /> : t("Restart")}
</Typography>
```

Answer (score 1):

I read a documentation about react-i18next
https://react.i18next.com/
The useTranslation is a hook like useState
So use this :
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
Not :
const {t} = useTranslation();
And :
Not : {t("Restart")}
But use this : {t("Restart")}
Because you must define tags :
if(cond)? something</>:something